I have no idea how to solve this (added third simulation)
I need to find formula for and transfer function of this circuit. I've been working on it for four days and still couldn't solve it.

Also a simulation I did in https://www.falstad.com/afilter/.
(added third simulation, and I don't understand, how that works, will try to solve again tomorrow)



I`ve been trying to solve this using these formulas, but it didn't give me the same result,


Here is graph for amplitude- frequency characteristic, I did in maxima, that those formulas gave me.

and code


Yeah, i did, should i add it to the post?

You should add to the post where your efforts took you - start with DC and high frequency behaviour. I find these sites to offer best value when there is an explicit answerable question near the bottom of a question post - find some advice in How to ask a Good Question

(In the Falstad model, where is Rn?)

I omited that, cause my teacher said, that it doesn't influence the outcome. I just checked it, and it actually doesn't

("[Rn] actually doesn't influence the outcome" I beg to differ: with that load, low frequency/DC response is only about 6/7 of HF response.)

i checked and added screenshot

(In the 1st schematic, Rn is connected to ground as it should. Without a load, a series resistor does indeed have no effect.)

Now i see what you mean't. I will try to solve it again tomorrow, but i am still not sure how are components connected. I hope that the third simulation is correct one

Here is a simulation.

Without changing anything, the network takes the form of a Wheatstone bridge. I apply Thevenin's theorem to the network shown in the photo, then I apply Millmann's theorem and I obtain the output voltage, with which I derive the transfer function of the network considering the load part of it:


Use nodal analysis for a systematic way of writing down the relevant and independent current balances for each node (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis). I will number the nodes as follows:

Node in the top left
Node in the top right
Node between \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$
Node on the bottom

We will choose node 4 as the reference node. All other node potentials will be relative to this potential. Furthermore, define the current flowing from the input terminal into node 1 as \$i_s\$ (the source current). Then the corresponding nodal equations in the frequency domain are given by:
\begin{equation}
I_s = (\frac{1}{R_3} + s C_2)(\Phi_1 - \Phi_2) + \frac{1}{R_1}(\Phi_1 - \Phi_3)
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
0 = (\frac{1}{R_3} + s C_2)(\Phi_2 - \Phi_1) + \frac{1}{R_2}(\Phi_2 - \Phi_3) + \frac{1}{R_H}\Phi_2
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
0 = \frac{1}{R_1}(\Phi_3 - \Phi_1) + \frac{1}{R_2}(\Phi_3 - \Phi_2) + sC_1 \Phi_3
\tag{3}
\end{equation}
Next we need to incorporate an additional equation due to the voltage source acting as our input signal with voltage \$V_s = \Phi_1\$, which is the additional equation needed (the corresponding current \$I_s\$ is an additional variable to be determined alongside the node potentials \$\Phi_k\$).
\begin{equation}
V_s = \Phi_1
\tag{4}
\end{equation}
The equations (1) to (4) can be summerized in a single vector valued equation:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
V_s
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
(\frac{1}{R_3} + s C_2)+\frac{1}{R_1} & -(\frac{1}{R_3} + s C_2) & -\frac{1}{R_1} & -1 \\
-(\frac{1}{R_3} + s C_2) & (\frac{1}{R_3} + s C_2)+\frac{1}{R_2}+\frac{1}{R_H} & -\frac{1}{R_2} & 0 \\
-\frac{1}{R_1} & -\frac{1}{R_2} & \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + sC_1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi_1\\
\Phi_2\\
\Phi_3\\
I_s
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{5}
\end{equation}
The next step lies in inverting the matrix to get desired output potential \$\Phi_2\$ in terms of the input voltage \$V_s\$. You can use software for this task as inverting a 4x4 matrix takes some time. Instead we may try to solve the equation system by hand. Start by substituting equation (4) into equations (1), (2) and (3). Additionaly substitute \$\Phi_2 = V_o\$. We get:
\begin{equation}
I_s = (\frac{1}{R_3} + s C_2)(V_s - V_o) + \frac{1}{R_1}(V_s - \Phi_3)
\tag{6}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
0 = (\frac{1}{R_3} + s C_2)(V_o - V_s) + \frac{1}{R_2}(V_o - \Phi_3) + \frac{1}{R_H}V_o
\tag{7}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
0 = \frac{1}{R_1}(\Phi_3 - V_s) + \frac{1}{R_2}(\Phi_3 - V_o) + sC_1 \Phi_3
\tag{8}
\end{equation}
Use equation (7) to determine \$\Phi_3\$ in terms of \$V_s\$ and \$V_o\$ as this equation only contains the variables \$\Phi_3\$, \$V_s\$, \$V_o\$ and \$\Phi_3\$ appears only once.
\begin{equation}
\Phi_3 = R_2(\frac{1}{R_3} + s C_2)(V_o - V_s) + V_o + \frac{R_2}{R_H}V_o
\tag{9}
\end{equation}
Now we can substitute (9) into (8), divide both sides by \$V_s\$, and solve for the desired transfer function \$\frac{V_o}{V_s} = H(s)\$. The transfer function is then given by
\begin{equation}
H(s) = \frac{V_o}{V_s} = \frac{A(s)C(s)+\frac{1}{R_1}}{A(s)B(s) - \frac{1}{R_2}}
\tag{10}
\end{equation}
where the functions \$A(s)\$, \$B(s)\$ and \$C(s)\$ are defined as
\begin{equation}
A(s) = \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + sC1\\
B(s) = \frac{R_2}{R_H} + 1 + R_2(\frac{1}{R_3} + sC_2)\\
C(s) = R_2(\frac{1}{R_3} + sC_2)
\end{equation}
Some tedious algebra later, we finally arrive at
\begin{equation}
H(s) = \frac{\frac{1}{R_1} + (\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2})\frac{R_2}{R_3} + (\frac{R_2}{R_3}C_1 + (\frac{R_2}{R_1} + 1)C_2)s + C_1 C_2 R_2 s^2}{((\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2})(\frac{R_2}{R_H} +1 +\frac{R_2}{R_3}) - \frac{1}{R_2}) + (C_1(\frac{R_2}{R_H}+1+\frac{R_2}{R_3})+(\frac{R_2}{R_1}+1)C_2)s + C_1 C_2 R_2 s^2}
\tag{11}
\end{equation}
If the observed output does not correspond to \$\Phi_2\$, than you will have to use (5) to get the transfer function for the other desired output.

HUUUUUUGEEEE thanks to you. You have really given me the direction i have to work in. Now i have to figure out the magic you did there. Have a great day
